# Update all rows with same id to same value and update only one of them with specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables `questions` and `answers`. Each question has 4 answers, One of them is the correct answer:

```
      Questions
+-------------------+
|  id  |  question  |
+------+------------+
|  1   |     q1     |
+------+------------+

                     Answers
+------+----------+--------------+---------------+
|  id  |  answer  |  is_correct  |  question_id  |
+------+----------+--------------+---------------+
|  1   |     a1   |       0      |       1       |
+------+----------+--------------+---------------+
|  2   |     a2   |       0      |       1       |
+------+----------+--------------+---------------+
|  3   |     a3   |       1      |       1       |
+------+----------+--------------+---------------+
|  4   |     a4   |       0      |       1       |
+------+----------+--------------+---------------+
```

I'm trying to update the `is_correct`. So for example, if the correct answer is number `3` and I want to set it to `4`, I would have to update the `is_correct` for number `3` to `0` and then update the `is_correct` for number `4` to `1`.

This could be done with 2 queries:

```
--First query
UPDATE answers SET is_correct = 0 WHERE question_id = 1

--Second query
UPDATE answers SET is_correct = 1 WHERE id = 4
```

Is it possible to achieve this with one query or this is the best way?

Answer (score 1):

For `MySQL` the query would be

`update answers set is_corrent=(id=4) where question_id=1;`

Answer (score 0):

Tested on postgreSQL, you might need to change some minor details (use [`CAST` function](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_cast.asp)?):

```
UPDATE answers SET is_correct = (id = 4)::int WHERE question_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO answers 
    (id, is_correct  , question_id  )
    VALUES 
        (3, 0, 1),
        (4, 1, 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        is_correct  = VALUES(is_correct)
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer and how it resolves the question being asked?